# Django: manage.py custom command not found

Tags: python, django, command

When I do `python manage.py help`

```
[myapp]
        update_overall_score 
        update_periodic_score
```

my custom command is listed, in which I can able to run `update_periodic_score` through `python manage.py update_periodic_score` but when I try the other one, I get the `Unknown command: 'update_overall_score'` error.

What would be the problem? Both the files are placed in `myapp/management/commands` directory with `__init__.py` in all the directories.

This is my update_overall_score.py,

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from myapp.models import Users

class Command(BaseCommand):
    """
    Updates the overall_score field of every user.
    """
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        all_users = Users.objects.all()
        try:
            for user in all_users:
                likes = user.likes_received.count()
                stars = user.stars_received.count()
                user.overall_score = likes + stars
                user.save()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            return
        print "Updated Overall Score."
        return
```

Comment: added the code. `likes_received` and `stars_received` are related name for user foreign key in the corresponding tables.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the docstring for your class would be better put in the [`help` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/#BaseCommand.help) so that you can get useful output from `python manage.py help update_overall_score`.

Comment: You don't need a try/catch if you are just going to exit the method (the exception raised will terminate your code block naturally). Run your code in the django shell to make sure it works first. You also should use `self.stdout.write` instead of `print`.

Comment: I'll take care of the try/except. It works well with the shell. My question is though the `update_overall_score` is listed, why it's telling that the command not found when I try to execute? It's more weird when the other one executes with out any complaint.

Comment: Can you import your command ? If Django gets an ImportError it might complain "command not found".

Comment: Give us output of `python manage.py shell`, `from myapp.managment.commands.update_periodic_score import Command`

Comment: `>>> from myapp.management.commands.update_overall_score import Command Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named update_overall_score`

Comment: @jpic - Yes, I can't import. :(

Comment: But I can import, `>>> from myapp.management.commands.update_periodic_score import Command`

Comment: Then use python -vv to find out why the import fails.

Comment: OMG!!! There was a space between filename and extension. Fixed it! It shouldn't has been listed first! :0

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact problem. After a few hours of searching through manage.py code it showed up that this was caused by my settings file configurations. I was using Mezzanine as my CMS. When you use it Mezzanine kind of says that you can put some apps under OPTIONAL_APPS variable, so I had my custom app under this variable but not in INSTALLED_APPS. Moved back to INSTALLED_APPS and everything started working as expected.

Make sure you have your application nowhere else than under INSTALLED_APPS. manage.py looks exactly to this constant.